# Получение "пустого" промежутка времени

Tags: php, алгоритм, массивы, время

Есть массив, содержащий начало периода (`start`) и конец периода (`end`). Параметр `period` приведен для удобства, а периоды - время когда человек был трудоустроен.

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [start] => 1375300800
            [end] => 1406836800
            [period] => 2013-08-01 - 2014-08-01
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [start] => 1335816000
            [end] => 1375300800
            [period] => 2012-05-01 - 2013-08-01
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [start] => 1235854800
            [end] => 1375300800
            [period] => 2009-03-01 - 2013-08-01
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [start] => 1320091200
            [end] => 1328040000
            [period] => 2011-11-01 - 2012-02-01
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [start] => 1298926800
            [end] => 1314820800
            [period] => 2011-03-01 - 2011-09-01
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [start] => 1175371200
            [end] => 1235854800
            [period] => 2007-04-01 - 2009-03-01
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [start] => 1170277200
            [end] => 1183233600
            [period] => 2007-02-01 - 2007-07-01
        )

)
```

Если конце периода (end) - пустой, то используется текущая дата (промежуток не закончен, длится по текущий момент).

Задача состоит в том, чтобы определить период N месяцев в который человек не работал. Причем даты могут пересекаться между собой в разных периодах (подработки) и могут быть представлены не последовательно.

Интересует только алгоритм, не нужно приводить весь код. Просто как бы вы сделали это сами?

**UPD:**

Один из вариантов я пытаюсь реализовать. Сейчас конкретизировал задачу, наверно, будет понятнее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Отсортировал по [start]
2. Array empty = new Array();

   empty.start = array.First().end
3. Прошелся в цикле по элементам:

   а. Если cur.start > empty.start + N => empty.end = cur.start - Выходим решение найдено

   б. Если cur.end => null - Выходим, решения нет

   в. if (cur.end > empty.start) empty.start = cur.end

Находит первый промежуток. Надеюсь получилось понятно.

@GrayHoax Для измененой задачи:

а. Если cur.start > empty.start => empty.end = cur.start => Пишим куда нибудь значение. Все остальное без изменений

Найдем ВСЕ промежутки когда человек не работал (ни работ ни подработок), отличные от нуля (если start и end даты, или приводимы к датам)

Может быть не понятно написал вот код на С# (c PHP я не сталкивался):

```
public class Period
{
    public DateTime Start {get; set;}
    public DateTime End {get; set;}
    public String Period {get; set;}
}

public List<Period> GetListOfEmptyPeriod(List<Period> list)
{    
    if (list == null || list.Count() == 0) return null;

    List<Period> result = new List<Period>();
    DateTime tmp = new DateTime();

    tmp = list.OrderBy(n=>n.start).First().End;

    foreach (var cur in list.OrderBy(n=>n.start))
    {
        if (cur.Start > tmp)
        {
            Period empty = new Period();
            empty.Start = tmp;
            empty.End = cur.Start;
            result.Add(empty);            
        }
        if (cur.End == null) 
        { 
            break; 
        }
        if (cur.End > tmp) 
        { 
            tmp = cur.End; 
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Почему в `a` выход? Может дата начата - неделю назад, тогда надо найти другие пробелы...

Comment: @GrayHoax - если вы в отсортированном массиве дошли до cur.end => null - то дальше можно не проверять, с более ранним началом вы уже проверили, а более поздние не имеет смысла - так как данный промежуток "съедает" все оставшееся время. Идея такая: отсортировать, сравнить end и start соседей (перекрытия учитываем в пункте в.)

Comment: @GrayHoax - действительно была ошибка, внес исправление - поменял порядок пунктов.

Comment: Этот вариант немного не подходит, ввиду участия в нем переменной N. Я внес изменения в задачу, уж простите.

Comment: @GrayHoax, подправил вам алгоритм, без N, идея таже